# How to correctly check database connection with mysql in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

First I'd like to precise that I've been searching on the internet for a solution to my problem and all I find is the classic

```
if(connection.open) return true;
```

solution that is in my case not working for my needs.

I'm working on an application. Before it runs I need to check connectivity to the MySQL database, if the connection isn't done, a new window is opened prompting the user for connection settings(username, server address, password...). In this window I have a test connection button to see if the connection is established, this is the code of the button_click event :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings();

    applicationSettings.ServerDatabase = tbdbName.Text;
    applicationSettings.ServerIp = tbServer.Text;
    applicationSettings.ServerUserName = tbUsername.Text;
    //applicationSettings.ServerPassword = pbPassword.SecurePassword;
    applicationSettings.MakeConnectionString();
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(applicationSettings.ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        MessageBox.Show(this, "connection string: "+applicationSettings.ConnectionString+"connection OK!", "OK !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "connection string : "+applicationSettings.ConnectionString+"error : " + ee.Message, "connection ERROOOOR", MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage.Error);

    }
    finally
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

}
```

If I enter only the server address "applicationSettings.ServerIp" and click the test connection button, the messageBox OK is shown and the connection string is :

> Server=127.0.0.1;Database=;Password=;

I guess this is perfectly logical, but I need to test if the connection is established to the database, also if I fill the login text box with any random value, the connection is established.

**question** : How can I use this to test if the connection is established with the database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to the database, issue a simple query like `SELECT 1 from <KnownTable>` and make sure you successfully receive the '1' back. This confirm that you have

1. Connected to the physical server (no network issues)
2. Authenticated with the database server (database is running and you have correct credentials)
3. Connected to the correct database

Comment: thnks @Babak , that helps

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings();
    applicationSettings.ServerIp = tbServer.Text;
    applicationSettings.MakeConnectionString();
   try
    {
         MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(applicationSettings.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        MessageBox.Show(this, "server found", "OK !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        connection.Close();
        applicationSettings.ServerDatabase = tbdbName.Text;
            try{
                applicationSettings.MakeConnectionString();
                connection = new MySqlConnection(applicationSettings.ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Database found", "OK !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                connection.Close();
                applicationSettings.ServerUserName = tbUsername.Text;
                applicationSettings.ServerPassword = pbPassword.SecurePassword;
                        try{
                            applicationSettings.MakeConnectionString();
                            connection = new MySqlConnection(applicationSettings.ConnectionString);
                            connection.Open();
                            MessageBox.Show(this, "Server,database and account are valid", "OK !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            }
                        catch(Exception ee){
                                           MessageBox.Show(this, "Error: Account  parameters not valid!! " + ee.Message, "connection ERROOOOR", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                           MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                           }
                           }
             catch(Exception ee){
                            MessageBox.Show(this, "Error: server is connected but the database not found!! " + ee.Message, "connection ERROOOOR", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                            MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                 }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Error: server not found " + ee.Message, "connection ERROOOOR", MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage.Error);

    }
    finally
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

}
```

Maybe it helps you ;)